# Need column comprised of data from date two weeks ago for comparison

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-comparison

Let me start by saying that I am somewhat new to SQL/Snowflake and have been putting together queries for roughly 2 months. Some of my query language may not be ideal and I fully understand if there's a better, more efficient way to execute this query.  Any and all input is appreciated. Also, this particular query is being developed in Snowflake.

My current query is pulling customer volumes by department and date based on a 45 day window with a 24 day lookback from current date and a 21 day look forward based on scheduled appointments.  Each date is grouped based on where it falls within that 45 day window: current week (today through next 7 days), Week 1 (forward-looking days 8-14), and Week 2 (forward-looking days 15-21).  I have been working to try and build out a comparison column that, for any date that lands within either the Week 1 or Week 2 group, will pull in prior period volumes from either 14 days prior (Week 1) or 21 days prior (Week 2) but am getting nowhere. Is there a best-practice for this type of column?  Generic example of the current output is attached. Please note that the 'Prior Wk' column in the sample output was manually populated in an effort to illustrate the way this column should ideally work.

I have tried several different iterations of count(case...) similar to that listed below; however, the 'Prior Wk' column returns the count of encounters/scheduled encounters for the same day rather than those that occurred 14 or 21 days ago.

```
Count(Case When datediff(dd,SCHED_DTTM,getdate()) 
      between -21 and -7 then 1 else null end
) as "Prior Wk"
```

I've tried to use an IFF statement as shown below, but no values return.

```
(IFF(ENCOUNTER_DATE > dateadd(dd,8,getdate()),
 count(case when ENC_STATUS in (“Phone”,”InPerson”) AND
 datediff(dd,ENCOUNTER_Date,getdate()) between 7 and 14 then 1 
 else null end), '0')
) as "Prior Wk"
```

Also have attempted creating and using a temporary table (example included) but have not managed to successfully pull information from the temp table that didn't completely disrupt my encounter/scheduled counts.  Please note for this approach I've only focused on the 14 day group and have not begun to look at the 21 day/Week 2 group. My attempt to use the temp table to resolve the problem centered around the following clause (temp table alias: "Date1"):

```
CASE when AHS.GL_Number = "DATEVISIT1"."GL_NUMBER" AND 
  datevisit1.lookback14 = dateadd(dd,14,PE.CONTACT_Date)
then "DATEVISIT1"."ENC_Count" 
else null end 
as "Prior Wk"*
```

I am extremely appreciative of any insight on the current best practices around pulling prior period data into a column alongside current period data.  Any misuse of terminology on my part is not deliberate.

[image: Query Output Example]

[image: Temp Table Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand your requirement but it sounds like you need to use window functions https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html, in this case likely a SUM window function. The LAG window function, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html, might also be of some help

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity around my question.  Your suggestion has been extremely helpful and, while I have not quite resolved my issue yet, I believe window functions are the right direction after working with them.  Thank you.